# Private Beta link on the help > asking page

Tags: bug, status-deferred, help-center

I was perusing the [help pages](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to make sure that my next question is on-topic for this site and I noticed something that was rather odd for graduated site, a link that says

> [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta)

Is this intentionally left over, or does it need to be removed?

Comment: Looks like it's a standard help question - shows on [SO] help page too - https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: As such it may be a question worth searching and/or asking on [meta.se]

Comment: that is weird I never noticed that before

Comment: it appears on Meta as well --> https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: I have posted a similar question on Meta --> https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310373/200242

Comment: I have set this to [meta-tag:status-deferred] meaning that I believe it to be a bug (in this case perhaps a documentation error) but one that needs to be deferred to SE staff to resolve via [meta.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the link should be removed from that location.

However, since it occurs in the Help Center of every site including Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange, for that to happen will require a software fix at a level higher than the site-specific issues that we can deal with in this Meta.  That level is [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

There is a question that has already been posted as a [bug] [“How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” is listed in every site’s help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290401/how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-is-listed-in-every-site-s-help-centre) where it awaits SE developer resources being allocated to resolving it.

At the moment it has few votes (just 24), and as such I suspect will be considered a low priority.  If it is important to you then I think you should upvote it, like I did (probably a few years ago).